# Does the Firebase Firestore Function onWrite support multiple params?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

The `#onWrite` Firebase Firestore function - I understand from [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) and several examples across the web that Firestore functions support ONE variable/param in the path, eg:

```
functions.firestore
  .document('tests/{firstId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => { ... })
```

... but I can't find docs or examples if it supports multiple params in the path, eg:

```
functions.firestore
  .document('tests/{firstId}/nested/{secondId}') //- note the secondId
  .onWrite((change, context) => { ... })
```

In my tests running on local Firestore emulator, this function doesn't fire.

Can anyone confirm if multiple params are supported or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does support multiple wildcards in the document path.  There is an example in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters).

If you're having a problem with the emulator, file a bug report with the [firebase-tools repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).

Comment: Thanks Doug will look into it further and post if needed.